# In visual studio, some lines of code have light grey background while debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio

What does it mean? I am debugging C# code.

Comment: is your code updated? are you using some optimizations?

Comment: can you provide a screen shot?

Comment: yes, it is optimized. 
How can I upload screenshot?

Comment: Here is the code sample with debug point and the line with greyed background

private void ProcessImage(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

        {

            string x = string.Empty; <= debug point

            try

            {

                WebRequestParameters requestObject = (WebRequestParameters)asyncResult.AsyncState;

                WebRequest request = requestObject.Request;

                                WebResponse response = request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult);

                Bitmap tile = new Bitmap(response.GetResponseStream()); <= grey background

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Grey lines are statements which are on the call stack, including other threads' call stacks. In other words, statements which started, but have not yet finished executing, are greyed. Try clicking on various functions listed in the call stack + switching to other threads and clicking.

Answer (score 9):

Those are the lines comprising the call stack *other* than the line for the current frame. Here's a picture:

[image: Call Stack Highlighting]
<sub>(source: [280z28.org](http://www.280z28.org/images/CallStackHighlighting.png))</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Have look in the options (Tools -> Options, Environment / Font and Colors). However, switching though the display Items, I cannot see anything configured with light gray background which could be relevant for debugging.

Comment: @Anton: he gave a suggestion of a way to find out, which is often more useful (teach a man to fish etc) than just being told the answer!