# Changing the background colour of lines in the stack

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, development-environment

I have just changed the colour scheme of my Visual Studio 2008 environment to have a dark backround with light text.

This is so much easier on the eyes.

The only problem is lines that are on the call stack... Those lines that are referred to in this thread here [in visual studio some lines of code have light grey background while debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192680/in-visual-studio-some-lines-of-code-have-light-grey-background-while-debugging)

These lines have a bright grey background, which against my light text means I cannot read the text at all. I have been through every single colour in Tools -> Options -> Fonts and Colours and cannot find one that matches.

How can I change the background for lines on the current call stack?

**Edit**

Ok this is seriously doing my head in now!

I have tried with several different styles from here : [Studio Styles](http://studiostyles.info/). They all have the same problem.

I have just fired up VS2005 and I am getting the same problem.

Here is a screen shot of what is going on :

[image: Screenshot]

What is going on!??

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found [vs2010 c# debugging highlight color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103549/vs2010-c-sharp-debugging-highlight-color):

```
Tools → Options → Fonts and Colors → Text Editor → Read-only Region
```

I only get the color from `Call Return New Context` when I double-click a different entry in the Call Stack window.

Answer (score 1):

```
Tools → Options → Fonts and Colors → Text Editor → Call Return New Context
```

This one does it for me, not sure what 'Call Return' (without new context) is for.

Comment: No that's not doing it.. Setting Call Return will set the colour of the currently selected call stack line, but Call Return New Context doesnt seem to have any effect..

Comment: Strange as, for me, 'Call Return New Context' highlights the stack frames for the current thread irrespective of where they are in the call stack (for me they render green rather than grey too).

Comment: Googling "Call Return New Context" brings up one page. This one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850489/problem-visual-studios-custom-fonts-and-colors
No one had the answer then. Perhaps a bug or maybe a curse (I get them often!).

Comment: OK, I've just set by backcolour to black and Call Return New Context to magenta and it works fine.  So I suspected that Resharper had 'fixed' the bug and disabled the add-in but, no, it still highlights correctly (magenta).  So perhaps it is the version of Visual Studio — I am on VS2008 version 9.0.21022.8 RTM.

Comment: Hmm even stranger. I am on 9.0.30729.1 SP.. Some environment issue perhaps. I am on Vista...