# vs2010 c# debugging highlight color

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging

The scenario is that I'm debugging some C# code in vs2010. I stop at a breakpoint. I step into a method. The current line is highlighted with yellow (I think by default). The line that I left before stepping into the method is now has a light grey background. Not bad if  you have a dark text, but I have white text. Can't read it at all.

So, I want to change it, but what is it called?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Both of these colors are customizable.  Go to the fonts and colors menu

- Tools -> Options
- Environment -> Fonts And Colors

The values you are interested in are

- Current Statement: this is the line currently displaying in yellow
- Read-Only Region: this is the line currently displaying in grey

Comment: Thanks. Is it just me or are those terrible names? That list of highlighting classes is just a mess. Maybe some categorizing of them might help.

Comment: @Jeff I agree the names are pretty bad.  It took me 10 minutes to track down the second name and I knew exactly what I was looking for.  Categorization would be a step in the right direction for sure

Comment: Unfortunately, while these change the current line when the cursor isn't on that line, they don't affect the foreground color when the cursor is on the same line--it always turns black on black for me, making debugging a nightmare.